# How do you make the reported step a multiple of the logging frequency in PyTorch-Lightning, not the logging frequency minus 1?

Tags: python, logging, pytorch-lightning

[*Warning!! pedantry inside*]

I'm using PyTorch Lightning to wrap my PyTorch model, but because I'm pedantic, I am finding the logger to be frustrating in the way it reports the steps at the frequency I've asked for, **minus 1**:

1. When I set `log_every_n_steps=100` in `Trainer`, my Tensorboard output shows my metrics at step 99, 199, 299, etc. Why not at 100, 200, 300?
2. When I set `check_val_every_n_epoch=30` in `Trainer`, my console output shows progress bar goes up to epoch 29, then does a `validate`, leaving a trail of console outputs that report metrics after epochs 29, 59, 89, etc. Like this:

```
Epoch 29: 100%|█████████████████████████████| 449/449 [00:26<00:00, 17.01it/s, loss=0.642, v_num=logs]
[validation] {'roc_auc': 0.663, 'bacc': 0.662, 'f1': 0.568, 'loss': 0.633}
Epoch 59: 100%|█████████████████████████████| 449/449 [00:26<00:00, 16.94it/s, loss=0.626, v_num=logs]
[validation] {'roc_auc': 0.665, 'bacc': 0.652, 'f1': 0.548, 'loss': 0.630}
Epoch 89: 100%|█████████████████████████████| 449/449 [00:27<00:00, 16.29it/s, loss=0.624, v_num=logs]
[validation] {'roc_auc': 0.665, 'bacc': 0.652, 'f1': 0.548, 'loss': 0.627}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Should I simply submit a PR to PL to fix this?

Comment: Why not just write log_every_n_steps=101 and check_val_every_n_epoch=31?

Comment: That will just make the sequence 100, 201, 302, 403 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. Python uses zero-based indexing so epoch counting starts at zero as well. If you want to change the behavior of what is being displayed you will need to override the default `TQDMProgressBar` and modify `on_train_epoch_start` to display an offsetted value. You can achieve this by:

```py
from pytorch_lightning.callbacks.progress.tqdm_progress import convert_inf

class LitProgressBar(TQDMProgressBar):
    def init_validation_tqdm(self):
        bar = super().init_validation_tqdm()
        bar.set_description("running validation...")
        return bar
    def on_train_epoch_start(self, trainer, *_) -> None:
        total_train_batches = self.total_train_batches
        total_val_batches = self.total_val_batches
        if total_train_batches != float("inf") and total_val_batches != float("inf"):
            # val can be checked multiple times per epoch
            val_checks_per_epoch = total_train_batches // trainer.val_check_batch
            total_val_batches = total_val_batches * val_checks_per_epoch
        total_batches = total_train_batches + total_val_batches
        self.main_progress_bar.reset(convert_inf(total_batches))
        self.main_progress_bar.set_description(f"Epoch {trainer.current_epoch + 1}")
```

Notice the +1 in the last line of code. This will offset the epoch displayed in the progress bar. Then pass your custom bar to your trainer:

```py
# Initialize a trainer
trainer = Trainer(
    accelerator="auto",
    devices=1 if torch.cuda.is_available() else None,  # limiting got iPython runs
    max_epochs=3,
    callbacks=[LitProgressBar()],
    log_every_n_steps=100
)
```

Finaly:

```py
trainer.fit(mnist_model, train_loader)
```

For the first epoch this will display:

```bash
GPU available: False, used: False
TPU available: False, using: 0 TPU cores
IPU available: False, using: 0 IPUs
HPU available: False, using: 0 HPUs

  | Name | Type   | Params
--------------------------------
0 | l1   | Linear | 7.9 K 
--------------------------------
7.9 K     Trainable params
0         Non-trainable params
7.9 K     Total params
0.031     Total estimated model params size (MB)

Epoch 1: 17%                        160/938 [00:02<00:11, 68.93it/s, loss=1.05, v_num=4]
```

and not the default

```bash
Epoch 0: 17%                        160/938 [00:02<00:11, 68.93it/s, loss=1.05, v_num=4]
```

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer. It addresses part 2. I've found that the answer to #1 is quite different, and is explained here: https://github.com/Lightning-AI/lightning/issues/2110